# iOS Dropbox API : Get thumbnails for videos with streamable URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, thumbnails, dropbox-api

I want to get a thumbnail from a video stored on Dropbox.

I use this method of the `DBRestClientDelegate`.

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)restClient loadedStreamableURL:(NSURL *)url forFile:(NSString *)path
{
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL: url options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime requestedTime = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:requestedTime actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%@",err);
    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
}
```

But when I want to create a thumbnail with this code, sometimes I have this error :

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa9914e82a0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12792 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12792),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

And sometimes it works.
But I think this method download the whole content of the URL, it results by a more long time to wait for obtain the thumbnail.

How can I resolve this error? And my code, it is the good way to get a thumbnail from a video stored on Dropbox?

Comment: I also have this error but can't figure out why it occurs. Did you find a solution?